# Split Associative Array

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to split an associative array.But What happen is that it just remove it keys and order it in ascending order.I want to get top 5 elements of associative array with both keys and values.

```
$AllQuestions = Question::model()->findAll($criteria);
        foreach ($AllQuestions as $aq) {
            $question = array();
            $question[$aq->id] = $aq->question;
            if ($aq->type == "Realistic") {
                $testViewModel->RealisticQuestions[$aq->id] = $aq->question;
            } else if ($aq->type == "Investigative") {
                $testViewModel->InvestigativeQuestions[$aq->id] = $aq->question;
            } else if ($aq->type == "Conventional") {
                $testViewModel->ConventionalQuestions[$aq->id] = $aq->question;
            } else if ($aq->type == "Enterprising") {
                $testViewModel->EnterpriseQuestions[$aq->id] = $aq->question;
            } else if ($aq->type == "Social") {
                $testViewModel->SocialQuestions[$aq->id] = $aq->question;
            } else if ($aq->type == "Artistic") {
                $testViewModel->ArtisticQuestions[$aq->id] = $aq->question;
            }
        }
        $testViewModel->InvestigativeQuestions = array_slice($testViewModel->InvestigativeQuestions, 0, $maxQuestions);
        $testViewModel->ArtisticQuestions = array_slice($testViewModel->ArtisticQuestions, 0, $maxQuestions);
        $testViewModel->ConventionalQuestions = array_slice($testViewModel->ConventionalQuestions, 0, $maxQuestions);
        $testViewModel->EnterpriseQuestions = array_slice($testViewModel->EnterpriseQuestions, 0, $maxQuestions);
        $testViewModel->SocialQuestions = array_slice($testViewModel->SocialQuestions, 0, $maxQuestions);
        $testViewModel->RealisticQuestions = array_slice($testViewModel->RealisticQuestions, 0, $maxQuestions);
```

Comment: What have you tried? A little code would be helpful for people trying to understand your question better

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: @VivekPradhan This is what I have tried so far

Comment: @FH-Inway This is what I have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_slice`

```
$new_array = array_slice($old_array, 0, 5, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use it:

$testViewModel->InvestigativeQuestions = array_slice($testViewModel->InvestigativeQuestions, 0, $maxQuestions, true);
$testViewModel->ArtisticQuestions = array_slice($testViewModel->ArtisticQuestions, 0, $maxQuestions, true);
$testViewModel->ConventionalQuestions = array_slice($testViewModel->ConventionalQuestions, 0, $maxQuestions, true);
$testViewModel->EnterpriseQuestions = array_slice($testViewModel->EnterpriseQuestions, 0, $maxQuestions, true);
$testViewModel->SocialQuestions = array_slice($testViewModel->SocialQuestions, 0, $maxQuestions, true);
$testViewModel->RealisticQuestions = array_slice($testViewModel->RealisticQuestions, 0, $maxQuestions, true);
```